# Error adding an article to a publication which is created on another database

Tags: replication, sql-server-2012

Im using sql server 2012 and its replication feature. Here im trying to manually create a publication and adding articles to it using script. I was able to create the publication successfully, but i have problems adding articles to it.

This is my script to add articles

```
EXEC ScriptDB.dbo.sp_addarticle 
            @publication = 'PublicationOne',
            @article = 'Departments',
            @source_object = 'Departments',
            @source_owner = 'dbo',
            @type = N'logbased',
            @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F,
            @identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual',
            @pre_creation_cmd = N'none'
```

The most important thing is, Departments table is in PublisherDB database and im runing this script from ScriptDB database. As i will be having many publishers, i will pass these values dynamically.

When i execute the above script, i get the following error

```
Msg 14027, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_addarticle, Line 590  [dbo].[Departments] does not exist in the current database.
```

Departments table does not exist in ScriptDB, but it is in PublisherDB database. So i changed the script to

```
EXEC PublisherDB.dbo.sp_addarticle 
            @publication = 'PublicationOne',
            @article = 'Departments',
            @source_object = 'Departments',
            @source_owner = 'dbo',
            @type = N'logbased',
            @schema_option = 0x000000000803509F,
            @identityrangemanagementoption = N'manual',
            @pre_creation_cmd = N'none'
```

now it says,

```
Msg 20026, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_MSreinit_article, Line 40 The publication 'PublicationOne' does not exist.
```

Tell me something, can't i run the script on another database to create a publication.

For example, consider this case, I have a master database and two publisher databases. I want to create two separate publication (one for each publisher database). Now can i execute the above script in master database to create publishers (using two publisher databases). Is this possible to implement.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[sp_addarticle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173857.aspx) must be executed at the Publisher on the publication database.  If you wish to publish the PublisherDB database then create the publication for PublisherDB and call sp_addarticle on the PublisherDB database to add articles to the publication.

Comment: I was creating the publication for PublisherDB on the ScriptDB and executing sp_addarticle on the PublisherDB. You are rite, i have to do everything on the publisherdb. thanks for the answer.